# Why do browsers complain about insecure resources on HSTS page

Tags: nginx, browser, hsts

I just witnessed a (for me) strange Browser behavior I don't quite understand. After I configured Nginx to support HSTS I tested one vhost with the following index.html:

```
<p>Internal Source:</p>
<img src="Picture1.jpg">
<p>Internal HTTP Source:</p>
<img src="http://samedomain.com/Picture1.jpg">
```

HSTS is set via:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
```

If I understand HSTS correctly the browser does something like s/http://samedomain.com/https://samedomain.com/ BEFORE it starts to load resources. Because I only have 443 listening and all resources are loading I think I am right.

Since everything is working fine, I have no clue why every Browser (tested with latest: Safari, Firefox, Chrome) is pointing out an insecure connection. Even the inspectors say that all resources where loaded over secure connections.

PS:
With "add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;" set no browser complains. But I can't set UIR because someone may has to load unsecured content. In this case it should obviously complain but it also should still display everything.

I hope someone can enlighten me :-)

Comment: Are you able to correct `index.html` or is it third party software?

Comment: In this case I am, but in productive environment I wont. Furthermore it is more a general question. The hole side is loaded via https and the browsers are complaining. WTF?

Comment: I do not have a definitive answer to your question, other than you are asking for insecure content from a secure page (irrespective of the browsers actions to enforce HSTS). However, the page should be using protocol-relative URLs for applicable resources.